# Call AngularFirestore from function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to call AngularFireStore from a promise function but using .this is not working. How can I call afs from the function?

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore) {
}

var TestMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        this.afs.collection('profiles')
        resolve();
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your scope.

You're trying to call `this` inside another function, so your `this` now refers to that function.

You should do something like:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore) {
}

var TestMethod = function() {
    var self = this;

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        self.afs.collection('profiles')
        resolve();
    });
    return promise;
};
```